# How to set max 3 days after rangepicker 1 date selected by nb-rangepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, nebular

I used nebular date range picker for filter data its working fine. currently, I want to set default maxDate 3 days after I select input first I try many methods but not worked for me.
Here is my TypeScript code

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { NbDateService } from '@nebular/theme';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'nb-datepicker-showcase',
      template: `
        <nb-card size="large">
          <nb-card-body>
            <input nbInput placeholder="Pick Date" [nbDatepicker]="formpicker">
            <nb-rangepicker #formpicker></nb-rangepicker>
          </nb-card-body>
        </nb-card>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./datepicker-example.scss'],
    })
    export class DatepickerShowcaseComponent {
    min: Date;
    max: Date;
  constructor(protected dateService: NbDateService<Date>) {
    this.min = this.dateService.addDay(this.dateService.today(), -2);
    this.max = this.dateService.addDay(this.dateService.today(), 2);
  }
    }
```

I also try to use use min、max date but not work for me

```
<input nbInput placeholder="Pick Date" [nbDatepicker]="picker">
<nb-rangepicker #picker [min]="min" [max]="max"></nb-rangepicker>
```

Comment: I don't see you decleare min and max variable in `DatepickerShowcaseComponent `

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (rangeChange) event listener on the nb-rangepicker element and then manipulate your date objects

```
<nb-rangepicker (rangeChange)="manipulateDate($event)" #dateRangePicker></nb-rangepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare max date in your controller.

```
max: Date = new Date();
max.setDate(new Date(this.min).getDate() + 2);
```

Comment: thanks but  I want selected date dynamically and the difference between both dates should be 3 days only

Comment: When ever the min date change you have to update the max date...

Comment: you have any idea where I used this function in nebular actually on ts file  its  working after closed

Comment: You can listen for dateChange event and if it is min date change update the max date